# IPv6: can't resolve host on Route 53 backed by CloudFront

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, ipv6, amazon-route53, amazon-cloudfront

I use AWS Route 53 in front of a CloudFront web distribution.  I'm trying to add IPv6 support for my CF distribution.

Following the AWS docs on [enabling IPv6](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesEnableIPv6) for Route 53, I added a `AAAA` record that is an `Alias` to my CF web distribution.

When I hit my `AAAA` record over IPv6 from cURL I get a:

```
curl -v -6 https://testcdnv6.mydomain.com/test.json
Could not resolve host: testcdnv6.mydomain.com
```

I know IPv6 is working fine on the machine I am running cURL on as facebook.com works:

```
curl -v -6 https://facebook.com
* Rebuilt URL to: https://facebook.com/
*   Trying 2a03:2880:f111:83:face:b00c:0:25de...
* Connected to facebook.com (2a03:2880:f111:83:face:b00c:0:25de) port 443 (#0)
* found 173 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 692 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_ECDSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
```

What am I missing here? `testcdnv6.mydomain.com` does NOT have an IPv4 A record.  I have waited more than an hour for DNS change to propagate.

`dig testcdnv6.mydomain.com ANY` does not return anything in the `ANSWER SECTION:`

Comment: You should check your resolver.. The Could not resolve host may indicate that your PC is failing with DNS resolution...

Comment: dns resolution is working as I can get facebook.com over IPv6 and IPv4

Comment: Without knowing the domain name I don't think there is much we can do to help you.

Comment: At the risk of asking the obvious: Did you enable IPv6 in the distribution itself?  Assuming you did, the next question: does the dxxxexample.cloudfront.net hostname for your CloudFront distribution work with your IPv6 test methodology?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot that was it, need to enable it in the CF distro before nameservers respond.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out because I used a route 53 alias to a CloudFront distribution, the DNS entry does not show up UNTIL you enable IPv6 support in your CloudFront configuration.  As soon as I configured it, dns queries started to return `AAAA` responses.

```
dig testcdnv6.mydomain.com AAAA +short
2600:9000:2013:ba00:6:6bd9:e340:93a1
2600:9000:2013:bc00:6:6bd9:e340:93a1
2600:9000:2013:ee00:6:6bd9:e340:93a1
2600:9000:2013:fa00:6:6bd9:e340:93a1
2600:9000:2013:600:6:6bd9:e340:93a1
2600:9000:2013:2a00:6:6bd9:e340:93a1
2600:9000:2013:8e00:6:6bd9:e340:93a1
2600:9000:2013:a200:6:6bd9:e340:93a1
```